# Dynamic DataGrid columns with Caliburn.micro

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I'm working on a translation tool and therefore I want to display (and edit) the translation data in my db. But now I'm already stuck with the displaying of the data.

I'm using Caliburn.micro as framework.

The data is passed to the frontend by the backend in a `List<List<string>>`, where the "outer" list represents the different phrases and the inner list a row with the first column being the original text and each further column the translations in each language. The language representation is made in an extra list (i.e. a row from the first table is `car|Auto|voiture` and the language representation is `de-DE|fr-FR`. The source language is fixed.)

The problem is now that when I pack my Lists in a `IObservableCollection<List<string>>`, the datagrid only displays two columns: Capacity and Count. Unfortunately I cannot put all data in a fixed object for the languages are not fixed, what means I could have 30 or even 100 of them.

Does anyone has an idea how I can get this done?

the view:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TranslationTool.EditDatabaseView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TranslationTool"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding TranslationData}">

        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

the viewmodel:

```
class EditDatabaseViewModel : Screen
{
    private IObservableCollection<List<string>> _translationData;

    public EditDatabaseViewModel()
    {
         TranslationData = new BindableCollection<List<string>>(DataStore.DB.GetTranslationsGrid());
    }

    public IObservableCollection<List<string>> TranslationData
    {
        get
        {
            return _translationData;
        }
        set
        {
            _translationData = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a DataTable with a dynamic number of columns and bind to this one?

Comment: @mm8, it can be so easy...Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As @mm8 wrote: Binding a `DataTable` to the DataGrid works like a charm!